# How to store syntax-highlighted text?

Tags: c++, qt, syntax-highlighting

I am creating a simple text editor with syntax highlighting from scratch as a school project. Right now, I use `QStringList` for storing the text data but later I'll be adding the syntax highlighting functionality and I don't know how should I store the data.

One option would be not to save the color information at all and continuously getting it from the code parser. But this would be probably very inefficient.

Maybe better idea is that there would be some list of structs (containing the color and the string) for every line which would store the color for every word in the text. But I'm not so sure how fast will this be either.

What is the best way to store these data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest two methods.

**Method 1: Store text with attributes**
Change your data structure to a container of structures.  The structure would contain a text string and a style variable:

```
struct Text_With_Properties
{
  std::string text;
  Properties  text_properties;
};
```

This may take up a lot more space and may not be the most efficient method.

**Method 2: Parse for Style Changes**
Many editors will display the text in normal font, then make another pass parsing for style changes.  For example, when a C++ keyword is found during the 2nd pass, the editor would change its style.

This method does not require any more space for the data, but does require more processing time.

Answer (score -2):

This question is probably too broad. But you could probably use HTML markup. It would give you an easy way to test, as well, as you could open up the output in a browser.